# What version of ReSharper do I have?

Tags: resharper, version

I can't remember if I purchased the C# version or the C#+VB version, and I'd like to find out as you need to know this when purchasing the upgrade to R# 6.

I can't find an *about* dialog anywhere. Can anyone help?

Comment: Downvote? Why? Does this not pertain to "software tools commonly used by programmers" (FAQ point 1)?

Comment: Lol the default for StackOverflow is to downvote any new questions. I've had questions that have been downvoted 3+ times and overtime they grow to 10+ upvotes. It's stupid

Answer (score 16, accepted):

'ReSharper/Help/About Jetbrains ReSharper' from the menu.

Comment: I ended up at this question because I was trying to figure out if I had Resharper installed or not. Moral of the story: if you don't have `Resharper` in the top menu bar, it is not installed

Answer (score 8):

From the menu in Visual Studio, Help > About Visual Studio

Comment: He needs the version of ReSharper, not Visual Studio

Comment: @ChrisBint: If you take a look at the dialog in question, it does indeed provide the info I asked.

Comment: ChrisBint's answer was more direct, but I'll leave my answer as an alternative.